# Yahoo Finance URL not working

Tags: yahoo-finance

I have been using the following URL to fetch historical data from yahoo finance for quite some time now but it stopped working as of yesterday.

https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY

When browsing to this site it says:

> Will be right back...
>
> Thank you for your patience.
>
> Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.

However, since this issue is still existing since yesterday I am starting to think that they discontinued this service?

My SO search only pointed me to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529918/read-csvhttp-ichart-finance-yahoo-com-table-csvs-spy-not-working), which was related to https though...

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?
How can I resolve this problem? Do they offer a different access to their historical data?

Comment: Seems to have happened without any warning whatsoever. What the hell.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore it happened to me as well but i did a very easy work around that is to make the urls anf fetch the data directly using pandas

Answer (score 124):

Yahoo has gone to a Reactjs front end which means if you analyze the request headers from the client to the backend you can get the actual JSON they use to populate the client side stores.

### Hosts:

- `query1.finance.yahoo.com` HTTP/1.0
- `query2.finance.yahoo.com` HTTP/1.1
  ([difference between HTTP/1.0 & HTTP/1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1))

If you plan to use a proxy or persistent connections use `query2.finance.yahoo.com`. But for the purposes of this post, the host used for the example URLs is not meant to imply anything about the path it's being used with.

---

### Fundamental Data

*(substitute your symbol for: AAPL)*

- `/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=`

**Inputs for the `?modules=` query:**

```py
    [
       'assetProfile',
       'summaryProfile',
       'summaryDetail',
       'esgScores',
       'price',
       'incomeStatementHistory',
       'incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly',
       'balanceSheetHistory',
       'balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly',
       'cashflowStatementHistory',
       'cashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly',
       'defaultKeyStatistics',
       'financialData',
       'calendarEvents',
       'secFilings',
       'recommendationTrend',
       'upgradeDowngradeHistory',
       'institutionOwnership',
       'fundOwnership',
       'majorDirectHolders',
       'majorHoldersBreakdown',
       'insiderTransactions',
       'insiderHolders',
       'netSharePurchaseActivity',
       'earnings',
       'earningsHistory',
       'earningsTrend',
       'industryTrend',
       'indexTrend',
       'sectorTrend']
```

**Example URL:**  *querying for all of the above modules*

- `https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=assetProfile%2CsummaryProfile%2CsummaryDetail%2CesgScores%2Cprice%2CincomeStatementHistory%2CincomeStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CbalanceSheetHistory%2CbalanceSheetHistoryQuarterly%2CcashflowStatementHistory%2CcashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CfinancialData%2CcalendarEvents%2CsecFilings%2CrecommendationTrend%2CupgradeDowngradeHistory%2CinstitutionOwnership%2CfundOwnership%2CmajorDirectHolders%2CmajorHoldersBreakdown%2CinsiderTransactions%2CinsiderHolders%2CnetSharePurchaseActivity%2Cearnings%2CearningsHistory%2CearningsTrend%2CindustryTrend%2CindexTrend%2CsectorTrend`

The `%2C` is the Hex representation of `,` and needs to be inserted between each module you request. [details about the hex encoding bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182356/what-is-2c-in-a-url)(if you care)

---

### Options contracts

- `/v7/finance/options/AAPL` (current expiration)
- `/v7/finance/options/AAPL?date=1679011200` (March 17, 2023 expiration)

**Example URL:**

- `https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/AAPL` (current expiration)
- `https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/AAPL?date=1679011200` (Match 17, 2023 expiration)

Any valid future expiration represented as a UNIX timestamp can be used in the `?date=` query. If you query for the current expiration the JSON response will contain a list of all the valid expirations that can be used in the `?date=` query. [*(here is a post explaining converting human-readable dates to UNIX timestamp in Python)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python)

---

### Price

- `/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?symbol=AAPL&period1=0&period2=9999999999&interval=3mo`

**Possible inputs for `&interval=`:** `1m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 90m, 1h, 1d, 5d, 1wk, 1mo, 3mo`

> `m` *(minute)* intervals are limited to 30days with `period1` and `period2` spaning a maximum of 7 days per/request. Exceeding either of these limits will result in an error and **will not round**

> `h` *(hour)* interval is limited to 730days with no limit to span. Exceeding this will result in an error and **will not round**

`period1=`: UNIX timestamp representation of the date you wish to **start** at.

> `d` *(day)*, `wk` *(week)*, `mo` *(month)* intervals with values less than the initial trading date will be rounded up to the initial trading date.

`period2=`: UNIX timestamp representation of the date you wish to **end** at.

> For all intervals: values greater than the last trading date will be rounded down to the most recent timestamp available.

**Add pre & post market data**

`&includePrePost=true`

**Add dividends & splits**

`&events=div%7Csplit`

`%7C` is hex for `|`. `,` will work but internally yahoo uses pipe

**Example URL:**

- `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?symbol=AAPL&period1=0&period2=9999999999&interval=1d&includePrePost=true&events=div%7Csplit`

The above request will return all price data for ticker AAPL on a 1-day interval including pre and post-market data as well as dividends and splits.

**Note:** *the values used in the price example URL for `period1=` & `period2=` are to demonstrate the respective rounding behavior of each input.`*

Comment: Hi @ryder-brooks, thanks for your great post! Could you post your github link?

Comment: How did you find the list of "all" modules? Can you outline the process in finding the list of modules. Thanks!

Comment: How did you uncover the modules and endpoints?

Comment: @pasta_sauce I monitored the network requests sent upon page load/interaction. There is actually an additional endpoint `/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/<YOUR_SYMBOL>?...` for more detailed financial data (it's what builds the balance sheet/cash flow/income statement pages) but the exhaustive list of query inputs is too large for a SO post. Plus you can get the same data returned from that endpoint for the entire market in a single request from edgar.

Comment: @RyderBrooks you are my man! I was trying to use jsonlite in R to scrap Yahoo finance and I got into massive confusion why my web pasted url dosent work, then I saw someone else is using a different url with the "query2". Your post just explained so much and so well!

Comment: @RyderBrooks you are brilliant! I would like to understand who to find out the URL links. Tried F12 on chrome and networks tab to see the request going out but I wasn't able to find out the link. Can you please share how one might go about finding the URL. I thought I should learn this not just for yahoo finace but it will be handy to understand how to get to any URL.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @serah the following is meant as general getting-started advice. While in the network tab the request has to have been made while you are recoding (the red dot in the left corner) and you should disable the cache in most scenarios. Also, a lot of times you are looking for XHR requests specifically. The filter bar can do a lot of stuff and is worth exploring but when looking for JSON payloads `mime-type: application/json` gets you most of the way there.  Unfortunately, the yahoo finance version is a bit more involved but I hope this response isn't completely useless to you.

Comment: @ryder-brooks What is the first part of the URL of that? I'm trying to access the parts in `QuoteTimeSeriesStore.timeSeries.trailingPegRatio`, but not able to get that. It should be somewhere in the *timeseries*. Also, do we also need to supply a specific header or agent?

Comment: @not2qubit I think you're running into the fact that yahoo only supplies pegRatio on a quarterly basis for free. However, you should be able to get the last 5 quarters if you query for `quarterlyPegRatio`.   ie: (works with both query1 & query2 no headers need be specified) `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/GS?symbol=GS&type=quarterlyPegRatio&period1=493590046&period2=1913180947`

Comment: @ryder-brooks Great! That works, but we have to specify both `period1` & `period2`.

Comment: @RyderBrooks Years later, still a valuable post. Thanks! Question: I have the paid subscription to Yahoo Plus Essentials. When you click on a company's financials, Income Statement, Balance Sheet, and Cash Flow, the "Download" link is unlocked for subscribers. Can you explain how I can see what http request is generated when I click "Download?" I tried to look at the network data in Chrome, but so far no luck on finding the right data.

Comment: @user658182 I do not have the paid version so I can't look and see what's going on. If it works like the download link in the historical price tab (which it probably doesn't) then you should be able to right click on it and say "copy link address". Then use some portion of that link in the search bar in the network tab to find the request that gets fired off when you click it. However, authentication complicates things so you might have to actually set breakpoints and step through the call stack to see what the code is doing, which is not trivial.

Comment: Keep in mind these are unofficial API's in the sense that they are not documented by Yahoo to be used by others.

Comment: @ryderbrooks thank you so much!  Been looking for how to scrape this for two days.  I see on yahoo's income statement they have peg ratio per quarter and annual, but that's buried in the api under a specific url.  I was using yahooquery and it doesn't grab out standing shares.

Answer (score 50):

It looks like they have started adding a required cookie, but you can retrieve this fairly easily, for example:

```
GET https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history
```

Responds with the header in the form:

```
set-cookie:B=xxxxxxxx&b=3&s=qf; expires=Fri, 18-May-2018 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.yahoo.com
```

You should be able to read this and attach it to your `.csv` request:

```
GET https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1492524105&period2=1495116105&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=tO1hNZoUQeQ
cookie: B=xxxxxxxx&b=3&s=qf;
```

Note the `crumb` query parameter, this seems to correspond to your `cookie` in some way. Your best bet is to `scrape` this from the HTML response to your initial GET request. Within that response, you can do a regex search for: `"CrumbStore":\{"crumb":"(?<crumb>[^"]+)"\}` and extract the crumb matched group.

It looks like once you have that `crumb` value though you can use it with the same `cookie` on any symbol/ticker for the next year meaning you shouldn't have to do the `scrape` too frequently.

---

To get current quotes just load:

`https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?interval=2m`

With:

- AAPL substituted with your stock ticker
- interval one of `[1m, 2m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 60m, 90m, 1h, 1d, 5d, 1wk, 1mo, 3mo]`
- optional `period1` query param with your epoch range start date e.g. `period1=1510340760`
- optional `period2` query param with your epoch range end date e.g. `period2=1510663712`

Comment: Any idea how to scrape that crumb?

Comment: @RupertPupkin For now you could probably get away with hard coding the crumb and cookie value in your application as they have an 1 year lifetime

Comment: @RupertPupkin Updated with how to scrape the crumb

Comment: Has anyone tried this yet? It's unbelievable that they would shut down a widely used service with no warning like that.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod It works I use it in my app, there's no guarentee they wont try and make it more secure though in the future :(

Comment: I scraped the crumb and formed the new url with the crumb, but I still got the error "Unauthorized" and "Invalid cookie". For example, the crumb I got was "IrLYRColfQG", and I formed the url https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/SHLM?period1=1494914550&period2=1497592950&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=IrLYRColfQG, but when I paste this url on my browser, it returns invalid cookie... any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: @LexL Hard to say without seeing your scraping code, if you link me to a gist or something i'll take a look :)

Comment: Whenever I visit the yahoo finance page from a browser, I can see that I always get the same crumb, but if I download the same link from my program, I get a different crumb, and that crumb is usually invalid for me to download the historic data. It doesn't make much sense to me.. :|

Comment: So it turns out that I didn't set the cookie like you showed in the post... it's resolved now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @EdW It is possible to get the minute data available in the charts using this method?

Comment: @hyprfrcb Yep just load the URL: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?period1=1510340760&period2=1510663712&interval=2m

Where AAPL is your `ticker`, `period1` + `period2` are optional epoch times (if you want a date range) and `interval` is requesting 2 minutely quotes. You can have the interval as 2m (2 mins), 5m (5 mins) 15m (15 mins) and 30m (30 mins) even though they are not listed as valid intervals by the API

Comment: @hyprfrcb Added an example into my answer above.

Comment: How are you issuing GET https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history? Is this an online http client? Python? I don't recognize it.

Comment: @user889742 Read up on "How to make HTTP requests" in whatever language you program in e.g. java.
You can test it using a web app such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: @Edd I just realized by using the v8 url one also gets the full history in a nice json format

Comment: replaced with this https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/%1 in kmymoney fixed the invalid cookie answer with v7 query format

Answer (score 23):

I managed to work out a .NET class to obtain valid token (cookie and crumb) from Yahoo Finance

For complete API library in fetching historical data from new Yahoo Finance, you may visit [YahooFinanceAPI](https://github.com/dennislwy/YahooFinanceAPI) in Github

Here is the class to grab the cookie and crumb

**Token.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace YahooFinanceAPI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class for fetching token (cookie and crumb) from Yahoo Finance
    /// Copyright Dennis Lee
    /// 19 May 2017
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class Token
    {
        public static string Cookie { get; set; }
        public static string Crumb { get; set; }

        private static Regex regex_crumb;
        /// <summary>
        /// Refresh cookie and crumb value Yahoo Fianance
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="symbol">Stock ticker symbol</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool Refresh(string symbol = "SPY")
        {

            try
            {
                Token.Cookie = "";
                Token.Crumb = "";

                string url_scrape = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}?p={0}";
                //url_scrape = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/history"

                string url = string.Format(url_scrape, symbol);

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                request.Method = "GET";

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {

                    string cookie = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie").Split(';')[0];

                    string html = "";

                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        html = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    if (html.Length < 5000)
                        return false;
                    string crumb = getCrumb(html);
                    html = "";

                    if (crumb != null)
                    {
                        Token.Cookie = cookie;
                        Token.Crumb = crumb;
                        Debug.Print("Crumb: '{0}', Cookie: '{1}'", crumb, cookie);
                        return true;
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }

            return false;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get crumb value from HTML
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="html">HTML code</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string getCrumb(string html)
        {

            string crumb = null;

            try
            {
                //initialize on first time use
                if (regex_crumb == null)
                    regex_crumb = new Regex("CrumbStore\":{\"crumb\":\"(?<crumb>.+?)\"}", 
                RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

                MatchCollection matches = regex_crumb.Matches(html);

                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    crumb = matches[0].Groups["crumb"].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Print("Regex no match");
                }

                //prevent regex memory leak
                matches = null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }

            GC.Collect();
            return crumb;

        }

    }
}
```

**Updated 1 Jun 17**
credits to @Ed0906
modify crumb regex pattern to `Regex("CrumbStore\":{\"crumb\":\"(?<crumb>.+?)\"}"`

Comment: Took a look at your code. Looks very good. Will try this tomorrow. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Thanks so much!  It works perfectly.  Among all of us, probably millions of hours saved!

Comment: Today, I replaced the outdated Yahoo Api with the new one based on your two classes. It worked out very well. Thank you very much.

Unfortunately, there was no Paypal button. So I was not able to donate for all the pain you saved me.    ;)

Comment: Just be careful with that reg ex as I've seen crumbs with symbols in whilst I've been experimenting

Comment: @Ed0906 do let me know your findings with weird crumb samples

Comment: @Dennis Today my app pulled down a crumb that looked like this for example: crumb=JNX1Dfqtj.n (with a . in) so you may want to add symbols to the reg ex (excluding " of course)

Comment: @Ed0906 thanks for sharing. I will update the regex pattern to Regex("CrumbStore\":{\"crumb\":\"(?<crumb>\\.+)\"}"

Comment: It is possible to get the minute data available in the charts using this method?

Comment: @hyprfrcb yahoo end of day price doesn't not provide minute data

Comment: I asked because the minute data is numerically present in the "Chart" tab up to 20 working days behind, though not in the "Historical Data" tab, just like the API did.

Comment: How about adding a usage example? I'm using something like request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(uri),new Cookie("B",YahooFinanceAPI.Token.Cookie.Substring(2))); but am not sure that it's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 15):

For the python lovers out there, I've updated the [yahooFinance.py](https://github.com/sjev/trading-with-python/blob/3.1.1/lib/yahooFinance.py) in tradingWithPython library.

There is also an example [notebook](https://github.com/sjev/trading-with-python/blob/master/scratch/get_yahoo_data.ipynb) based on the tips by Ed0906, demonstrating how to get the data step by step. See it on

Comment: This works excellent part of the time and I get `status_code` `200`, but sometimes it fails randomly and I get `status_code` `401`. I just did a `for` loop and added a `try` and `except`. Thanks!

Comment: You only need to get a cookie-crumb pair once, these should be valid for about a year.

Comment: Have the code together that generates  
     <url = http://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAAP?period1=1494862721&period2=1495726721&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=py9AgjRPaqF cookie: B=66lgrj1cib1au&b=3&s=qq>
which looks fine   
the  
     response = request.urlopen(url)
returns  
    HTTP Error 400 Unknown Version
Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 14):

In this forum: https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503/page/3

Nixon said:

> Hi All - This feature was discontinued by the Finance team and they will not be reintroducing that functionality.

Answer (score 13):

The URL for downloading historical data is now something like this:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/SPY?period1=1492449771&period2=1495041771&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=9GaimFhz.WU

Note the above URL will not work for you or anyone else. You'll get something like this:

```
{
    "finance": {
        "error": {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "description": "Invalid cookie"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that Yahoo is now using some hashing to prevent people from accessing the data like you did. The URL varies with each session so it's very likely that you can't do this with a fixed URL anymore.

You'll need to do some scrapping to get the correct URL from the main page, for example:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/history?p=SPY

Answer (score 9):

I had found another yahoo site that does not require cookies, but generates jason output: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/YHOO?range=2y&interval=1d&indicators=quote&includeTimestamps=true

it was pointed out from here: https://www.stock-data-solutions.com/kb/how-to-load-historical-prices-from-yahoo-finance-to-excel.htm

As it turned out they seem to support 'perod1' and 'period2' (in unix time) parameters which could be used instead of the 'interval'.

```
String quoteSite = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/"
                   + symbolName + "?"
                   + "period1=" + period1
                   + "&period2=" + period2
                   + "&interval=1d&indicators=quote&includeTimestamps=true";
```

And the following parses Jason for me:

```
JSONObject topObj = new JSONObject(inp);
Object error = topObj.getJSONObject("chart").get("error");
if (!error.toString().equals("null")) {
    System.err.prinltn(error.toString());
    return null;
}
JSONArray results = topObj.getJSONObject("chart").getJSONArray("result");
if (results == null || results.length() != 1) {
    return null;
}
JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray timestamps = result.getJSONArray("timestamp");
JSONObject indicators = result.getJSONObject("indicators");
JSONArray quotes = indicators.getJSONArray("quote");
if (quotes == null || quotes.length() != 1) {
    return null;
}
JSONObject quote = quotes.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray adjcloses = indicators.getJSONArray("adjclose");
if (adjcloses == null || adjcloses.length() != 1) {
   return null;
}
JSONArray adjclose = adjcloses.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("adjclose");
JSONArray open = quote.getJSONArray("open");
JSONArray close = quote.getJSONArray("close");
JSONArray high = quote.getJSONArray("high");
JSONArray low = quote.getJSONArray("low");
JSONArray volume = quote.getJSONArray("volume");
```

Comment: I think they actually require cookies as well nowadays.

Comment: @AlbertCheng I do not think so. I run without cookies and it works.

Comment: if that is the case it is amazing!

Answer (score 5):

I'm in the same boat.  Getting there slowly.  The download link on the historical prices page still works.  So I added the export cookies extension to firefox, logged in to yahoo,  dumped the cookies.  Used the crumb value from interactive session and I was able to retrieve values.  Here's part of a test perl script that worked.

```
use Time::Local;

# create unix time variables for start and end date values: 1/1/2014 thru 12/31/2017
$p1= timelocal(0,0,0,1,0,114);
$p2= timelocal(0,0,0,31,11,117);

$symbol = 'AAPL';

# create variable for string to be executed as a system command
# cookies.txt exported from firefox
# crumb variable retrieved from yahoo download data link
$task = "wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --no-check-certificate -T 30 -O          $symbol.csv \"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/$symbol?period1=$p1&period2=$p2&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=7WhHVu5N4e3\" ";

#show what we're executing
print $task;

# execute system command using backticks
`$task`;

#output is AAPL.csv
```

It'll take a while to automate what I do.  Hopefully yahoo will simplify or give some guidance on it if they really intend for people to use it.

Comment: Can you add a few comment lines to your code? It's not clear to me, what `task` is. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Fully working **PHP example**, based on this post and related sources:

```
function readYahoo($symbol, $tsStart, $tsEnd) {
  preg_match('"CrumbStore\":{\"crumb\":\"(?<crumb>.+?)\"}"',
    file_get_contents('https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/' . $symbol),
    $crumb);  // can contain \uXXXX chars
  if (!isset($crumb['crumb'])) return 'Crumb not found.';
  $crumb = json_decode('"' . $crumb['crumb'] . '"');  // \uXXXX to UTF-8
  foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
    if (0 !== stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie: ')) continue;
    $cookie = substr($header, 14, strpos($header, ';') - 14);  // after 'B='
  }  // cookie looks like "fkjfom9cj65jo&b=3&s=sg"
  if (!isset($cookie)) return 'Cookie not found.';
  $fp = fopen('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/' . $symbol
    . '?period1=' . $tsStart . '&period2=' . $tsEnd . '&interval=1d'
    . '&events=history&crumb=' . $crumb, 'rb', FALSE,
    stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => 'GET',
      'header' => 'Cookie: B=' . $cookie))));
  if (FALSE === $fp) return 'Can not open data.';
  $buffer = '';
  while (!feof($fp)) $buffer .= implode(',', fgetcsv($fp, 5000)) . PHP_EOL;
  fclose($fp);
  return $buffer;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$csv = readYahoo('AAPL', mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 2017), mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 2017));
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### Python

I used this code to get cookie (copied from [fix-yahoo-finance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance)):

```
def get_yahoo_crumb_cookie():
    """Get Yahoo crumb cookie value."""
    res = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/history')
    yahoo_cookie = res.cookies['B']
    yahoo_crumb = None
    pattern = re.compile('.*"CrumbStore":\{"crumb":"(?P<crumb>[^"]+)"\}')
    for line in res.text.splitlines():
        m = pattern.match(line)
        if m is not None:
            yahoo_crumb = m.groupdict()['crumb']
    return yahoo_cookie, yahoo_crumb
```

then this code to get response:

```
cookie, crumb = get_yahoo_crumb_cookie()
params = {
    'symbol': stock.symbol,
    'period1': 0,
    'period2': int(time.time()),
    'interval': '1d',
    'crumb': crumb,
}
url_price = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{symbol}'

response = requests.get(url_price, params=params, cookies={'B': cookie})
```

This looks nice as well http://blog.bradlucas.com/posts/2017-06-03-yahoo-finance-quote-download-python/

Comment: This is good: http://blog.bradlucas.com/posts/2017-06-03-yahoo-finance-quote-download-python/ thanks @Lucas03

Answer (score 4):

For java lovers.

You can access your cookies from a URLConnection this way.

```
 //  "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY";
 URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
 ...  
 for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : con.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey() == null 
            || !entry.getKey().equals("Set-Cookie"))
            continue;
        for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
           // store your cookie
           ...
        }
 }
```

now you can search for the crumb in the yahoo site:

```
String crumb = null;
InputStream inStream = con.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader irdr = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
BufferedReader rsv = new BufferedReader(irdr);

Pattern crumbPattern = Pattern.compile(".*\"CrumbStore\":\\{\"crumb\":\"([^\"]+)\"\\}.*");

String line = null;
while (crumb == null && (line = rsv.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher matcher = crumbPattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.matches()) 
        crumb = matcher.group(1);
}
rsv.close();
```

and finally, setting the cookie

```
String quoteUrl = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/IBM?period1=1493425217&period2=1496017217&interval=1d&events=history&crumb="
                           + crumb
...
List<String> cookies = cookieStore.get(key);
if (cookies != null) {
    for (String c: cookies) 
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", c);
}
...
con.connect();
```

Comment: I like it more than the other methods.....   It is possible to get the minute data available in the charts using this method?

Answer (score 3):

I used a php script using fopen() to access the financial data, here are the snippets that I modified to get it back to work:

Creating the timestamps for start date and end date:

```
$timestampStart = mktime(0,0,0,$startMonth,$startDay,$startYear);
$timestampEnd = mktime(0,0,0,$endMonth,$endDay,$endYear);
```

Force fopen() to send the required cookie with hard coded values:

```
$cookie="YourCookieTakenFromYahoo";

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
            "Cookie: B=".$cookie."\r\n"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Use fopen() to get the csv file:

```
$ticker="TickerSymbol";
$crumb="CrumbValueThatMatchesYourCookieFromYahoo";

$handle = fopen("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/".$ticker."?period1=".$timestampStart."&period2=".$timestampEnd."&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=".$crumb."", "r", false, $context);
```

Now you can do all the magic you did before inside this while loop:

```
while (!feof($handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($handle, 5000);
}
```

Make sure to set your own values for `$ticker`, `$crumb` and `$cookie` in the snippets above.
Follow [Ed0906's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44050039/1405376) on how to retrieve `$crumb` and `$cookie`.

Comment: Do mind adding a little more to this answer. I understand it but I can't seem to execute it. Not sure if I'm using the right Cookie?

Comment: Hi @Chad, what would you like me to elaborate in more detail? When checking for the set cookies in Yahoo!'s site, copy the value of the cookie with the name 'B'. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Okay, it was combination of few minors on my part, but for anybody else this is what the cookie and crumb look like. `$cookie = "95eg6lcisb25&b=3&s=oq"; $crumb = "nGLaX9jgD2B";` The easiest way to get the cookie is just just a cookie plug in for browser.  Thanks to @jm. Also I just want to say that I hate yahoo for doing this to all of with out notice!

Comment: It is possible to get the minute data available in the charts using this method?

Comment: I get `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized in E:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 31` error message. Did they fix this already? Also, my cookie B value is somehow much longer than yours... This answer works though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348197/4114325

Answer (score 3):

I was on the same boat. I managed to get the CSV downloaded from Yahoo with some vb.net frankencode I made from bits and pieces off Google, SOF and some head-scratching.

However, I discovered Intrinio (look it up), signed up, and my free account gets me 500 historic data api calls a day, with much more data and much more accurate than Yahoo. I rewrote my code for the Intrinio API, and I'm happy as a clam.

BTW, I don't work or have anything to do with Intrinio, but they saved my butt big time...

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of this [service](https://github.com/robomotic/valueviz)

Basic info [here](http://quantprice.herokuapp.com/)

**Daily prices**

You need to be familiar with RESTFUL services.

https://quantprice.herokuapp.com/api/v1.1/scoop/day?tickers=MSFT&date=2017-06-09

**Historical prices**

You have to provide a date range :

https://quantprice.herokuapp.com/api/v1.1/scoop/period?tickers=MSFT&begin=2012-02-19&end=2012-02-20

If you don't provide begin or end it will use the earliest or current date:

https://quantprice.herokuapp.com/api/v1.1/scoop/period?tickers=MSFT&begin=2012-02-19

**Multiple tickers**

You can just comma separate tickers:

https://quantprice.herokuapp.com/api/v1.1/scoop/period?tickers=IBM,MSFT&begin=2012-02-19

**Rate limit**

All requests are rate limited to 10 requests per hour. If you want to register for a full access API send me DM on twitter. You will receive an API key to add to the URL.

We are setting up a paypal account for paid subscription without rates.

**List of tickers available**

https://github.com/robomotic/valueviz/blob/master/scoop_tickers.csv

I am working also to provide fundamental data and company data from EDGAR.
Cheers.

Comment: These are displaying previous trading day's data. Not realtime.

Comment: Hello, I have just added this functionality so you can now check real time prices from NYSE and NASDAQ with 5 minute delay, example below:

https://nasdaqviz.herokuapp.com/api/v1.1/markets/data/nsdaq/realtime/MSFT

Answer (score 3):

**VBA**

Here are some VBA functions that download and extract the cookie / crumb pair and return these in a `Collection`, and then use these to download the csv file contents for a particular code.

The containing project should have a reference to the 'Microsoft XML, v6.0' library added (other version might be fine too with some minor changes to the code).

```
Sub Test()
    Dim X As Collection

    Set X = FindCookieAndCrumb()

    Debug.Print X!cookie
    Debug.Print X!crumb

    Debug.Print YahooRequest("AAPL", DateValue("31 Dec 2016"), DateValue("30 May 2017"), X)
End Sub


Function FindCookieAndCrumb() As Collection
    ' Tools - Reference : Microsoft XML, v6.0
    Dim http    As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim cookie  As String
    Dim crumb   As String
   Dim url     As String
    Dim Pos1    As Long
    Dim X       As String

    Set FindCookieAndCrumb = New Collection

    Set http = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history"

    http.Open "GET", url, False
    ' http.setProxy 2, "https=127.0.0.1:8888", ""
    ' http.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
    ' http.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"
    ' http.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-ZA,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
    http.send

    X = http.responseText

    Pos1 = InStr(X, "CrumbStore")

    X = Mid(X, Pos1, 44)

    X = Mid(X, 23, 44)

    Pos1 = InStr(X, """")

    X = Left(X, Pos1 - 1)

    FindCookieAndCrumb.Add X, "Crumb"

    '======================================

    X = http.getResponseHeader("set-cookie")

    Pos1 = InStr(X, ";")

    X = Left(X, Pos1 - 1)

    FindCookieAndCrumb.Add X, "Cookie"

End Function

Function YahooRequest(ShareCode As String, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, CookieAndCrumb As Collection) As String
    ' Tools - Reference : Microsoft XML, v6.0
    Dim http            As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim cookie          As String
    Dim crumb           As String
    Dim url             As String
    Dim UnixStartDate   As Long
    Dim UnixEndDate     As Long
    Dim BaseDate        As Date

    Set http = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    cookie = CookieAndCrumb!cookie
    crumb = CookieAndCrumb!crumb

    BaseDate = DateValue("1 Jan 1970")

    If StartDate = 0 Then StartDate = BaseDate

    UnixStartDate = (StartDate - BaseDate) * 86400
    UnixEndDate = (EndDate - BaseDate) * 86400

    url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" & ShareCode & "?period1=" & UnixStartDate & "&period2=" & UnixEndDate & "&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=" & crumb

    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie
    http.send

    YahooRequest = http.responseText
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

For those Excel/VBA users I have used the suggestions above to develop a VBA method to extract historical prices from the updated Yahoo website. The key code snippets are listed below and I have also provided my testing workbook.

First a request to get the Crumb and Cookie values set before attempting to extract the data from Yahoo for the prices..

```
Dim strUrl                      As String: strUrl = "https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup?s=%7B0%7D"    'Symbol lookup used to set the values
Dim objRequest                  As WinHTTP.WinHttpRequest

Set objRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, True
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    .send
    .waitForResponse
    strCrumb = strExtractCrumb(.responseText)
    strCookie = Split(.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"), ";")(0)
End With
```

See the following [Yahoo Historical Price Extract](http://www.xlautomation.com.au/free-spreadsheets/yahoo-historical-price-extract) link to my website for a sample file and more details on the method I have used to extract historical security prices from the Yahoo website

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to do 2 requests to get Yahoo data.  I use this link https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAAP/history?period1=1474000669&period2=1505536669&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

You could grab the cookie from the this but instead it includes that data for you historical quote in Json format. After I download the page I scarpe the Json data out of it. Saves a url request.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript

Find cookie;

```
match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('B=([^;]+)'));
alert (match[1]);
```

Find crumb;

```
i=document.body.innerHTML.search("CrumbStore")
if (i>=0) alert (document.body.innerHTML.substr(i+22,11))
```

Find crumb for mobile;

```
i=document.body.innerHTML.search('USER={\"crumb\":'); 
if (i>=0) alert(document.body.innerHTML.substr(i+15,11));
```

and it's probably best to wait for the page (e.g https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/goog)   to load up first, you can
check it with;

```
document.readyState
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to those mentioned so far (Yahoo, Google and Intrinio) is to get the historical data from Alpha Vantage for free. Their web service delivers intra-day, daily, adjusted stock prices and 50+ technical indicators. They even deliver straight to Excel - also for free - through Deriscope. (I am the author of the latter.)

Comment: Alpha Vantage do not have indexes or most of the information already existing on Yahoo...

Comment: Not true! Try this url https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=^DJI&outputsize=compact&apikey=xxx where you must replace the last xxx with your own Alpha Vantage key. You will see the data for the ^DJI index. You should also know that Yahoo does not deliver real time prices for this or any other index, whereas Alpha Vantage does (with one min delay). The respective url is https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=^DJI&interval=1min&apikey=xxx

Comment: But it returned me the error `"Error Message": "Invalid API call`. I am indeed looking for intraday world indexes (N225, HSI, IXIC, BOVESPA, DAX, etc.) and most of the services simply dont provide these (`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=^DJI&interval=1min&apikey=xxx`). I tried escaping it as `%5E` and as `^`

Comment: I tried on chrome right now the url https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IXIC&interval=1min&apikey=xxx where xxx stands for my user key. When you try it, you should replace xxx with your own key, which you get it from the Alpha Vantage site. Have you done that? Is your key valid? You can check if it is valid by trying to get prices on MSFT for example.

Comment: This works now!. for the ^IXIC and ^DJI as before. But other world stock indexes (^N225, ^HSI, ^DAX, ^BOVESPA) from other countries do not appear. Or i am not knowing the proper symbols for them?. How should i seek a list of symbols?

Comment: Alpha Vantage has informed me their focus is on stocks, not on indices. Nevertheless they will try to support in the future at least some of the most liquid indices.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to connect yahooFinance api with java. just add the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yahoofinance-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>YahooFinanceAPI</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix that I have found to work well. Please see my post:

[Yahoo Finance API / URL not working: Python fix for Pandas DataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112403/python-fix-for-yahoo-finance-pandas-datareaders-get-data-yahoo/44166463#44166463) where I followed the steps in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance to: $ pip install fix_yahoo_finance --upgrade --no-cache-dir (and also upgraded pandas_datareader to be sure) and tested ok:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo('BHP.AX', start='2017-04-23', end='2017-05-24')
```

Also note that the order of the last 2 data columns are 'Adj Close' and 'Volume' so for my purpose, I have reset the columns to the original order:

```
cols = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']
data = data.reindex(columns=cols)
```

Comment: The problem I have is that Yahoo is probably going to stop any data access every time we find a fix. I am going to try writing symbols into a preset Google spreadsheet with Google finance code to do the price lookups and then read back the results. It looks like the limit is 250 stocks for a Google spreadsheet so will have to loop this 13 times for all Nasdaq stocks and then again for NYSE and Amex. Has any one tried this ?

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3 users  change to

url='https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAAP?period1=1494605670&period2=1495815270&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=IJ.ilcJlkrZ'

from

url='https://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/AAAP/chartdata;type=quote;range=10d/csv/'

and

response = request.urlopen(url)
to
response = requests.get(url,cookies={'B':cookie})
data in response.text

the data format is totally different but at least its working fine for now

Answer (score 1):

I've combined some of the above ideas that handles the crumb / cookie refresh, specifically from @Dennis, and created a vb.net class that can be called like this:

```
Dim f = Await YahooFinanceFactory.CreateAsync
Dim items1 = Await f.GetHistoricalDataAsync("SPY", #1/1/2018#)
Dim items2 = Await f.GetHistoricalDataAsync("^FTSE", #1/1/2018#)
```

The class itself is here:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Namespace YahooFinance
    Public Class YahooHistoryPrice

        Public Property [Date] As DateTime

        Public Property Open As Double

        Public Property High As Double

        Public Property Low As Double

        Public Property Close As Double

        Public Property Volume As Double

        Public Property AdjClose As Double
    End Class

    Public Class YahooFinanceFactory
        Public Property Cookie As String
        Public Property Crumb As String
        Public Property CrumbUrl As String = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}?p={0}"
        Public Property DownloadUrl As String = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{0}?period1={1}&period2={2}&interval=1d&events={3}&crumb={4}"

        Public Property Timeout As Integer = 5
        Public Property NoRefreshRetries As Integer = 10
        Public Property NoDownloadRetries As Integer = 10
        Private Property Regex_crumb As Regex

        Public Shared Async Function CreateAsync(Optional noRefreshRetries As Integer = 10, Optional noDownloadRetries As Integer = 10, Optional timeout As Integer = 5, Optional crumbUrl As String = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}?p={0}", Optional downloadUrl As String = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{0}?period1={1}&period2={2}&interval=1d&events={3}&crumb={4}") As Task(Of YahooFinanceFactory)
            Return Await (New YahooFinanceFactory With {
                .NoRefreshRetries = noRefreshRetries,
                .NoDownloadRetries = noDownloadRetries,
                .Timeout = timeout,
                .CrumbUrl = crumbUrl,
                .DownloadUrl = downloadUrl
            }).RefreshAsync()
        End Function

        Public Async Function GetHistoricalDataAsync(symbol As String, dateFrom As Date) As Task(Of IEnumerable(Of YahooHistoryPrice))
            Dim count As Integer = 0

            If Not IsValid Then
                Throw New Exception("Invalid YahooFinanceFactory instance")
            End If

            Dim csvData = Await GetRawAsync(symbol, dateFrom, Now).ConfigureAwait(False)

            If csvData IsNot Nothing Then
                Return ParsePrice(csvData)
            End If

            Return Array.Empty(Of YahooHistoryPrice)
        End Function

        Public Async Function GetRawAsync(symbol As String, start As DateTime, [end] As DateTime) As Task(Of String)
            Dim count = 0

            While count < NoDownloadRetries
                Try
                    Dim cookies = New CookieContainer
                    cookies.Add(New Cookie("B", If(Cookie.StartsWith("B="), Cookie.Substring(2), Cookie), "/", ".yahoo.com"))

                    Using handler = New HttpClientHandler With {.CookieContainer = cookies}
                        Using client = New HttpClient(handler) With {.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Timeout)}
                            Dim httpResponse = Await client.GetAsync(GetDownloadUrl(symbol, start)).ConfigureAwait(False)
                            Return Await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
                        End Using
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    If count >= NoDownloadRetries - 1 Then
                        Throw
                    End If
                End Try

                count += 1
            End While

            Throw New Exception("Retries exhausted")
        End Function

        Private Function ParsePrice(ByVal csvData As String) As IEnumerable(Of YahooHistoryPrice)
            Dim lst = New List(Of YahooHistoryPrice)
            Dim rows = csvData.Split(Convert.ToChar(10))
            For i = 1 To rows.Length - 1
                Dim row = rows(i)
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(row) Then
                    Continue For
                End If
                Dim cols = row.Split(","c)
                If cols(1) = "null" Then
                    Continue For
                End If
                Dim itm = New YahooHistoryPrice With {.Date = DateTime.Parse(cols(0)), .Open = Convert.ToDouble(cols(1)), .High = Convert.ToDouble(cols(2)), .Low = Convert.ToDouble(cols(3)), .Close = Convert.ToDouble(cols(4)), .AdjClose = Convert.ToDouble(cols(5))}
                If cols(6) <> "null" Then
                    itm.Volume = Convert.ToDouble(cols(6))
                End If
                lst.Add(itm)
            Next

            Return lst
        End Function

        Public ReadOnly Property IsValid() As Boolean
            Get
                Return Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Cookie) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Crumb)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Function GetDownloadUrl(symbol As String, dateFrom As Date, Optional eventType As String = "history") As String
            Return String.Format(DownloadUrl, symbol, Math.Round(DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(dateFrom), 0), Math.Round(DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(Now.AddDays(-1)), 0), eventType, Crumb)
        End Function

        Public Function GetCrumbUrl(symbol As String) As String
            Return String.Format(Me.CrumbUrl, symbol)
        End Function

        Public Function DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(dateTime As DateTime) As Double
            Return (dateTime.ToUniversalTime() - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds
        End Function

        Private Async Function RefreshAsync(Optional symbol As String = "SPY") As Task(Of YahooFinanceFactory)
            Dim count = 0

            While count < NoRefreshRetries And Not IsValid
                Try
                    Using client = New HttpClient With {.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Timeout)}
                        Dim httpResponse = Await client.GetAsync(GetCrumbUrl(symbol)).ConfigureAwait(False)
                        Me.Cookie = httpResponse.Headers.First(Function(f) f.Key = "Set-Cookie").Value.FirstOrDefault?.Split(";"c)(0)
                        Dim html = Await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
                        Me.Crumb = GetCrumb(html)
                        If Crumb IsNot Nothing Then
                            Return Me
                        End If
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    If count >= NoRefreshRetries - 1 Then
                        Cookie = ""
                        Crumb = ""
                        Throw
                    End If
                End Try

                count += 1
            End While

            Cookie = ""
            Crumb = ""
            Throw New Exception("Could not refresh YahooFinanceFactory")
        End Function

        Private Function GetCrumb(html As String) As String
            Dim crumb As String = Nothing

            If Regex_crumb Is Nothing Then
                Regex_crumb = New Regex("CrumbStore"":{""crumb"":""(?<crumb>.+?)""}", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant Or RegexOptions.Compiled, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            End If

            Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex_crumb.Matches(html)
            If matches.Count > 0 Then
                crumb = matches(0).Groups("crumb").Value
                crumb = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(crumb)
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Regex no match")
            End If

            Return crumb
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the ready one which provides full access. without malfunctioning:

```
tickers='AAPL' 

from pandas_datareader import data as wb

new_data = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers :

    new_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source ='yahoo', start = '2004-1-1')['Adj Close']

a = new_data[t]
```

Comment: "without malfunctioning" until Yahoo changes their API and library maintainer doesn't want to use it anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get current and historical data from [google finance api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516633/how-to-work-with-google-finance). Works very good for me.

Comment: the problem of google finance is that they throttle the data stream, after a few calls, you won't get any data.