# Yahoo historical quotes in Excel - follow on

Tags: vba, excel, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I see the note on the Yahoo blog stating they've discontinued support for iChart and I see this answer [Yahoo Finance Historical data downloader url is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044263/yahoo-finance-historical-data-downloader-url-is-not-working) discussing the newer request format for historical data.

Here is the original snippet of code I was using to download the historical data (it was part of a loop that created a tab in a spreadsheet per stock symbol)

```
With Sheets(SheetName).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & yahoosymbols & "&a=09&b=29&c=1984&d=04&e=12&f=2020&g=w&ignore=.csv", Destination:=DestinationRange)
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = False
        .FieldNames = False
    End With
```

and here is the new code using the new version of the URL

```
With Sheets(SheetName).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" & yahoosymbols & "?period1=947570400&period2=1577858400&interval=1wk&events=history&crumb=RhdXrQKrUXZ", Destination:=DestinationRange)
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = False
        .FieldNames = False
    End With
```

If I copy and paste the url (subbing a stock symbol for the yahoosymbols variable) then it works fine in a browser.

But when I run this code then I get an excel 1004 error and says it is unable to open the url

Any thoughts? I am not a VBA guy so might be making a real amateur mistake. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest Record Macro of building the web query manually and compare the generated code with yours. Another option could be Power Query if your Excel version supports it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the link. Yahoo recently moved HTTP to HTTPS and also requires cookies (notice the "Crumb" at the end of URL)? The "Download Data" link on https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/YHOO/history?period1=947570400&period2=1577858400&interval=1wk&filter=history&frequency=1wk now has that. If you copy the link and open it in another browser you will notice that it will not open. You will need to establish a session with the Yahoo Finance server in order to get the crumb. I have not done this before so will have to check

Comment: Thanks folks. I actually got this guy's solution to work. http://www.xlautomation.com.au/free-spreadsheets/yahoo-historical-price-extract It was a little different approach to the query than what I was using, but handled all of the cookie and crumb stuff well

Answer (score 0):

The urls you are using are not valid any more.
But since you are not a vba guy and you only need YF data in Excel, why don't you use the Deriscope Excel addin?
Disclaimer: I am the Deriscope's author.