# Exploding a line from a file gives Undefined Offset error in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, offset, php-7, explode

I am trying to read a file (`$txtFile`) line-by-line. Then store the different items in the line (`$line`) separated by comma in an array (`$pieces`). The code is given below.

```
 <?php
    include_once __DIR__.'/connect.php';

    function createURL($ticker)
    {
        $currentPeriod = time(); 
        return "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/$ticker?period1=1538917807&period2=1541596207&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=6DH0b71wPwr";
    }

    function getCSVFile($url, $outputFile)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        $content = str_replace("Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume", "", $content);
        $content = trim($content);
        file_put_contents($outputFile, $content);
    }

    function fileToDatabase($txtFile, $tableName)
    {
        $file = fopen($txtFile, "r");
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $line = fgets($file);
            $pieces = explode(",", $line);
            print_r($pieces);
            $date = $pieces[0];
            $open = $pieces[1];
            $high = $pieces[2];
            $low = $pieces[3];
            $close = $pieces[4];
            $adj_close = $pieces[5];
            $volume = $pieces[6];
            $amount_change = $adj_close-$open;
            $percent_change = ($amount_change/$open)*100;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if (!$result) {
                $createQuery = "CREATE TABLE $tableName (
                    date TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY,
                    open FLOAT,
                    high FLOAT,
                    low FLOAT,
                    close FLOAT,
                    adj_close FLOAT,
                    volume INT,
                    amount_change FLOAT,
                    percent_change FLOAT
                )";
                $conn->query($createQuery);
            }

            $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES (
                '$date', '$open', '$high', '$low', '$close', '$adj_close', '$volume', '$amount_change', '$percent_change'
            )";
            $conn->query($insertQuery);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }

function main()
{
    $pathToTickerFile = __DIR__."/tickerMaster.txt";
    $mainTickerFile = fopen($pathToTickerFile, "r");
    while (!feof($mainTickerFile)) {
        $companyTicker = fgets($mainTickerFile);
        $companyTicker = trim($companyTicker);

        $fileURL = createURL($companyTicker);
        $companyTxtFile = __DIR__."/txtFiles/".$companyTicker.".txt";
        getCSVFile($fileURL, $companyTxtFile);
        fileToDatabase($companyTxtFile, $companyTicker);
    }
    fclose($mainTickerFile);
    echo "The stocks have been downloaded!";
}

main();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Stock Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 6
```

I am using PHP-7.0 & I am unable to understand what's wrong with this code. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: do a `print_r($pieces);`. That should give you a head-start

Comment: Mind empty lines. Also consider `file()` or `fgetcsv()` and `list()` for such tasks.

Comment: `print_r($pieces);` gives `Array ( [0] => )`

Comment: Are you sure all the lines contain the number of commas you expect?

Comment: Wait a minute.  I am posting the complete code!

Comment: See also https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php+read+csv+undefined+offset+1

Comment: Also if you can post the first few lines of the file, that would help.

Comment: @NigelRen Just did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix, would be to check that you have a line with 7 elements, so after your explode, just check how many elements the array has and skip the rest of the processing if there aren't enough values...

```
$pieces = explode(",", $line);
if ( count($pieces) != 7)   {
    continue;
}
$date = $pieces[0];
// ....
```

You should also look into using prepared statements as the offer more security, although you will still have to do a substitution for the table name as you do now (you can't have a table name as a bind variable).

Also as a recommendation, when doing an INSERT,always list the column names ...

```
INSERT INTO $tableName (date, open, ... )
   VALUES ('$date', '$open', ...)
```

as this ensures that it's clear which column is where and if any table changes are made that the INSERT is explicit about which values it is using for which columns.

Comment: The files are indeed empty because `file_get_contents($url)` isn't getting data. `$url` is working fine but `$content` is empty. Can you please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Can you give me 1 line from the tickerMaster.txt file so I can test it.

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the start of your script, I get `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents(https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TSLA?period1=1538917807&period2=1541596207&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=6DH0b71wPwr): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`

Comment: This is the warning I am getting every time for each link

Comment: But typing that URL in the browser downloads the CSV file

Comment: You must have logged in on the browser.  Is there any documentation which tells you how to use the API and how to login?

Comment: Also getting `Warning: file_put_contents(/projects/stock-analyzer/txtFiles/TSLA.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: No. There isn't any documentation or login requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183291/discussion-between-gautam-vashisht-and-nigel-ren).

Comment: There are a couple of references - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working/44050039#44050039 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249819/php-code-for-yahoo-api-for-downloading-csv-file

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains a blank line (or possibly multiple). You'll usually see this at the very end of the file.

Because of this, `explode()` returns an array with a single empty value, while you expect 7 (keys 0 through 6).

Before exploding the line to an array, check if it is indeed empty. Or count the array after creating it, and validate the expected number of keys are present.

Answer (score 1):

Before indexing into the array, you might check if the number of items in `$pieces` by for example counting the number if items that explode returns:

```
$file = fopen($txtFile, "r");
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $pieces = explode(",", $line);
    if (count($pieces) > 6) {
        $date = $pieces[0];
        $open = $pieces[1];
        $high = $pieces[2];
        $low = $pieces[3];
        $close = $pieces[4];
        $adj_close = $pieces[5];
        $volume = $pieces[6];
    }
}
```