# wget can't download yahoo finance data any more

Tags: wget

Since a few weeks ago I'm not able to download Yahoo finance data any more:

```
$ wget -O GLD.USA_20170612.txt --no-check-certificate http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GLD&a=2&b=1&c=2017&d=11&e=30&f=2017&ignore=.csv
--2017-06-12 12:21:28--  http://gld.usa_20170612.txt/
Resolving gld.usa_20170612.txt (gld.usa_20170612.txt)... failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘gld.usa_20170612.txt’
--2017-06-12 12:21:28--  http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GLD&a=2&b=1&c=2017&d=11&e=30&f=2017
Resolving chart.finance.yahoo.com (chart.finance.yahoo.com)... 87.248.114.12, 87.248.116.11, 87.248.116.12, ...
Connecting to chart.finance.yahoo.com (chart.finance.yahoo.com)|87.248.114.12|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GLD&a=2&b=1&c=2017&d=11&e=30&f=2017 [following]
--2017-06-12 12:21:28--  https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GLD&a=2&b=1&c=2017&d=11&e=30&f=2017
Connecting to chart.finance.yahoo.com (chart.finance.yahoo.com)|87.248.114.12|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-06-12 12:21:28 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

They have changed something. I picked up a new URL from the site, but it still does not work:

```
$ wget https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GLD?period1=1494584558&period2=1497262958&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=GGHpj6ucgIy
--2017-06-12 12:27:24--  https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GLD?period1=1494584558
Resolving query1.finance.yahoo.com (query1.finance.yahoo.com)... 87.248.116.11, 87.248.116.12, 87.248.114.11, ...
Connecting to query1.finance.yahoo.com (query1.finance.yahoo.com)|87.248.116.11|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

I don't understand why it mentions Username and Password. When I click the Download button at https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/GLD/history?p=GLD, it does not ask for the Username and Password. So it seems that data can be downloaded without a subscription.

If someone knows a proper wget implementation for downloading Yahoo finance data, please share it here.

...

Update:

Thanks to the current replies, I was hinted that "cookies" might be involved here. While searching for the similar problem with cookies in the keywords, I found the following threads:

[Yahoo Finance Historical data downloader url is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044263/yahoo-finance-historical-data-downloader-url-is-not-working)

[Yahoo Finance URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working)

Unfortunately this is too complex for me...
I would appreciate a little help in making this work.

Comment: _"I don't understand why it mentions Username and Password. When I click the Download button at https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/GLD/history?p=GLD, it does not ask for the Username and Password"_ - then I suggest you open that download link in a _private_ browser tab for a change, and find the explanation ...

Comment: You're missing a cookie, you could check what cookies you send when you click the download button. I suspect Yahoo doesn't want you accessing their finance data without using their own API. When you do that you are bypassing their ads.

Comment: If I could identify which cookie, and store it offline... How to instruct `wget` to use the cookie?

Comment: better of using curl then... but it is possible with wget, checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4272783/777850) or google some more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to deal with Yahoo cokies I have written the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

symbol=$1
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
tomorrow=$(date --date='1 days' +%Y%m%d)

first_date=$(date -d "$2" '+%s')
last_date=$(date -d "$today" '+%s')

wget --no-check-certificate --save-cookies=cookie.txt https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/$symbol/?p=$symbol -O crumb.store

crumb=$(grep 'root.*App' crumb.store | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep CrumbStore | sed 's/"CrumbStore":{"crumb":"\(.*\)"}/\1/')

wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=cookie.txt "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/$symbol?period1=$first_date&period2=$last_date&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=$crumb" -O $symbol.csv

rm cookie.txt crumb.store
```

Usage example:

```
$ sh stockdownload_yahoo.sh QQQ 20170508
```

Examples supported date formats:

```
$ date -d 20170328 +%s
1490652000
$ date -d 2017-03-28 +%s
1490652000
$ date -d "Mar 28 2017" +%s
1490652000
```