# Using wget in shell trouble with variable that has \

Tags: bash, special-characters, wget

I'm trying to run a script for pulling finance history from yahoo. Boris's answer from this thread
[wget can't download yahoo finance data any more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498924/wget-cant-download-yahoo-finance-data-any-more)
works for me ~2 out of 3 times, but fails if the crumb returned from the cookie has a "\" character in it.
Code that sometimes works looks like this

```
#!usr/bin/sh
symbol=$1
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
tomorrow=$(date --date='1 days' +%Y%m%d)
first_date=$(date -d "$2" '+%s')
last_date=$(date -d "$today" '+%s')
wget --no-check-certificate --save-cookies=cookie.txt https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/$symbol/?p=$symbol -O C:/trip/stocks/stocknamelist/crumb.store
crumb=$(grep 'root.*App' crumb.store | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep CrumbStore | sed 's/"CrumbStore":{"crumb":"\(.*\)"}/\1/')
echo $crumb
fileloc=$"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/$symbol?period1=$first_date&period2=$last_date&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=$crumb"
echo $fileloc
wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=cookie.txt $fileloc -O c:/trip/stocks/temphistory/hs$symbol.csv
rm cookie.txt crumb.store
```

But that doesn't seem to process in wget the way I intend either, as it seems to be interpreting as described here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/758080/getting-scheme-missing-error-with-wget
Any suggestions on how to pass the $crumb variable into wget so that wget doesn't error out if $crumb has a "\" character in it?

Edited to show the full script. To clarify I've got cygwin installed with wget package.  I call the script from cmd prompt as (example where the script above is named "stocknamedownload.sh, the stock symbol I'm downloading is "A" from the startdate 19800101)

```
c:\trip\stocks\StockNameList>bash stocknamedownload.sh A 19800101
```

This script seems to work fine - unless the crumb returned contains a "\" character in it.

Comment: `$'"'"`? That's a lot of mess to go through for no reason.

Comment: ("for no reason" meaning that adding more literal quotes doesn't in any way substitute for missing syntactic quotes).

Comment: That said -- trying to reproduce this from the code you provided, I don't have anything that matches `root.*App` in my `crumb.store`. Can you try to add enough content that others can see the problem themselves?

Comment: Added additional content that should help clarify/reproduce.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: (Hmm -- looks like Cygwin doesn't ship `jq`. That's annoying -- and frankly, I'm a bit surprised; it's been in widespread use for long enough now that I'd have expected them to pick it up).

Comment: BTW, I notice `C:`-style paths. Does that mean you're using a Windows-native wget executable rather than the cygwin-provided one?

Comment: I searched for and added the wget cygwin package.  Wget is executing for me ok (the script is working *most* of the time.  I was able to add the jq package as well, though after 15 minutes of browsing the tutorial, I haven't been able to follow on how it's going to change the result of my $crumb variable as it is executed on the wget line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following implementation appears to work 100% of the time -- I'm unable to reproduce the claimed sporadic failures:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o pipefail

symbol=$1
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
tomorrow=$(date --date='1 days' +%Y%m%d)
first_date=$(date -d "$2" '+%s')
last_date=$(date -d "$today" '+%s')

# store complete webpage text in a variable
page_text=$(curl --fail --cookie-jar cookies \
  "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/$symbol/?p=$symbol") || exit

# extract the JSON used by JavaScript in the page
app_json=$(grep -e 'root.App.main = ' <<<"$page_text" \
           | sed -e 's@^root.App.main = @@' \
                 -e 's@[;]$@@') || exit

# use jq to extract the crumb from that JSON
crumb=$(jq -r \
          '.context.dispatcher.stores.CrumbStore.crumb' \
          <<<"$app_json" | tr -d '\r') || exit

# Perform our actual download
fileloc="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/$symbol?period1=$first_date&period2=$last_date&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=$crumb"
curl --fail --cookie cookies "$fileloc" >"hs$symbol.csv"
```

Note that the `tr -d '\r'` is only necessary when using a native-Windows `jq` mixed with an otherwise native-Cygwin set of tools.

Comment: Thanks! I had to add curl to my cygwin package. But the solutions works well.  Many thanks!

Comment: If it's working, consider clicking the checkbox next to the answer to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding quotes *to* the value of the variable instead of quoting the expansion. You are also trying to use tools that don't know what JSON is to process JSON; use `jq`.

```
wget --no-check-certificate \
     --save-cookies=cookie.txt \
     "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/$symbol/?p=$symbol" \
     -O C:/trip/stocks/stocknamelist/crumb.store


# Something like thist; it's hard to reverse engineer the structure
# of crumb.store from your pipeline.
crumb=$(jq 'CrumbStore.crumb' crumb.store)
echo "$crumb"

fileloc="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/$symbol?period1=$first_date&period2=$last_date&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=$crumb"
echo "$fileloc"
wget --no-check-certificate \
     --load-cookies=cookie.txt "$fileloc" \
     -O c:/trip/stocks/temphistory/hs$symbol.csv
```

Comment: Is your answer intended for java implementation? Trying to implement as a shell script with cygwin. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @JimL, `jq` is not a Java application -- it's intended for use from shell. See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: (Also, while I'm not sure that this will work as-is -- a copy of the `crumb.store` would help to validate -- the general approach of using a program that understands JSON to decode a JSON string has a rational relationship to solving your immediate problem; if you have a literal `\"` substring, that's a JSON encoding of the literal `"`; if you have `jq` decoding a string, it'll decode that literal as part of it).

Comment: ...actually, if you want that unescaping, it would need to be `jq -r`, not bare `jq`.

Comment: This is my first foray into Unix style regular expressions (installed cygwin just to try to get a working solution), so I could use a little more hand holding on this.  I installed the jq package and naively tried to convert my crumb variable to json style by adding the line.     crumb=jq($crumb)

Comment: Looking through the tutorial on jq, it looks like it's supposed to do very similar things to grep and sed.  I don't believe my issue is actually with the $crumb variable.  The echo of $crumb is giving the expected result whether there is a "\" in it or not.  My problem (I believe) is in how wget is interpretting the variable when there's a "\" in it.  The wget call seems to convert the "\" to %5C.

Comment: @chepner, ...so, I've gotten a look at the data -- it's a HTML document; not well-formed JSON as a whole by any means.

Comment: @JimL, `echo` is not trustworthy. Use `declare -p crumb` rather than `echo "$crumb"` to get an accurate description of the variable's contents.

Comment: @JimL, the other thing is that when `sed` returns `\"`, the **actual data** is just `"` with no backslash proceeding it. If that backslash gets sent back to the browser, that's a problem. Using a compliant JSON decoder (like `jq`) will prevent that from happening.