# Get stock data program with python

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I tried to get stock information from Yahoo with following code.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31)
f = web.DataReader('SNE', 'yahoo', start, end)
print(f)
```

But there is error like following ....
Please someone help me..

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    140             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 141                 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    142 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     59 
---> 60     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     61         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

~\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    742     addrlist = []
--> 743     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    744         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked,
**httplib_request_kw)
    355         else:
--> 356             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    357 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1238         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1240 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1284             body =
_encode(body, 'body')
-> 1285         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)    1286 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)    1233             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1234         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)    1235 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)    1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)    1027 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    963             if self.auto_open:
--> 964                 self.connect()
    965             else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    165     def connect(self):
--> 166         conn = self._new_conn()
    167         self._prepare_conn(conn)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    149             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 150                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    151 

NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000001B3783DC18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    437                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 438                     timeout=timeout
    439                 )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    648             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 649                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    650             retries.sleep()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    387         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 388             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    389 

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ichart.finance.yahoo.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /table.csv?s=SNE&a=0&b=1&c=2010&d=11&e=31&f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000001B3783DC18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-7d307edbe1a3> in <module>()
      3 start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
      4 end = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31)
----> 5 f = web.DataReader('SNE', 'yahoo', start, end)
      6 print(f)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, access_key)
    115                                 adjust_price=False, chunksize=25,
    116                                 retry_count=retry_count, pause=pause,
--> 117                                 session=session).read()
    118 
    119     elif data_source == "yahoo-actions":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py in read(self)
     75     def read(self):
     76         """ read one data from specified URL """
---> 77         df = super(YahooDailyReader, self).read()
     78         if self.ret_index:
     79             df['Ret_Index'] = _calc_return_index(df['Adj Close'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in read(self)
    155         if isinstance(self.symbols, (compat.string_types, int)):
    156             df = self._read_one_data(self.url,
--> 157                                      params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    158         # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    159         elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in
_read_one_data(self, url, params)
     72         """ read one data from specified URL """
     73         if self._format == 'string':
---> 74             out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
     75         elif self._format == 'json':
     76             out = self._get_response(url, params=params).json()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in
_read_url_as_StringIO(self, url, params)
     83         Open url (and retry)
     84         """
---> 85         response = self._get_response(url, params=params)
     86         text = self._sanitize_response(response)
     87         out = StringIO()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in
_get_response(self, url, params)
    112         # initial attempt + retry
    113         for i in range(self.retry_count + 1):
--> 114             response = self.session.get(url, params=params)
    115             if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    116                 return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in get(self, url,
**kwargs)
    529 
    530         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 531         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    532 
    533     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    516         }
    517         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 518         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    519 
    520         return resp

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    637 
    638         # Send the request
--> 639         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    640 
    641         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    500                 raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    501 
--> 502             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    503 
    504         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ichart.finance.yahoo.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /table.csv?s=SNE&a=0&b=1&c=2010&d=11&e=31&f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000001B3783DC18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Comment: A connection to ichart.finance.yahoo.com could not be made. Basically because that hostname does not exist. Maybe the service is down or discontinued.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I see..

Comment: To bypass ichart.finance.yahoo.com see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044263/yahoo-finance-historical-data-downloader-url-is-not-working/44982256#44982256

Answer (score 0):

If you want to utilize yahoo finance, use Yahoo_finance API.

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
```

and when you want to retrieve values for a specific share use:

```
Share('<Your Share Ticker Name>')
```

Then you can retrieve historical data and what not with something like

```
Share('Your Share Ticker Name>').get_historical(<start_date>, <end_date>)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Here is the page for the API https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Maybe the code I tried is old right?

Thanks

Comment: Yea, lots of the API's are deprecated and will not work.

Comment: Thank you for replying :)
It's very hard to learn Python for the beginner like me...hehe