# How to retrieve historical stock data with python?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

I've been looking around for a stable function to fetch stock data in my program. Yahoo_finance is broken completely now, even the current day data retrievers return a None type. Previously I've had success with a [stock downloader written by Andrew Galeazzi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044263/yahoo-finance-historical-data-downloader-url-is-not-working), but just a couple days ago the downloader stopped working, and now I am met with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/somename/PycharmProjects/StockGUI/test1.py", line 57, in module>
    print (get_crumble_and_cookie('KO'))
  File "C:/Users/somename/PycharmProjects/StockGUI/test1.py", line 26, in get_crumble_and_cookie
    cookie_str = match.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Are there any historical stock data retrievers out there that are currently working?

Comment: Have you tried [`googlefinance`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance)? Or are you strictly looking to fetch from Yahoo!?

Comment: [This](https://www.alphavantage.co) has api to fetch historical data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pandas-datareader` package. Example code below.

```
import datetime as dt
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

start_date = dt.datetime(1980, 1, 1)
dat = data.DataReader('googl', 'yahoo', start_date, dt.datetime.today())
dat.to_csv('googl.csv', mode='w', header=True)
```

I used `pandas-datareader==0.5.0` and Python 3.6.2. Incidentally, [`pandas-datareader` docs](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew.html#v0-5-0-july-25-2017) seem to indicate that Yahoo recently changed the API. Also, `pandas-datareader` has options for pulling [dividend/split data](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html) as well.