# Has Yahoo suddenly today terminated its finance download API?

Tags: yahoo-finance

For months I've been using a url like this, from perl:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$s&f=ynl1 #returns yield, name, price;
```

Today, 11/1/17, it suddenly returns a 999 error.

Is this a glitch, or has Yahoo terminated the service?

I get the error even if I enter the URL directly into a browser as, eg:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=INTC&f=ynl1
```

so it doesn't seem to be a 'crumb' problem.

Note: This is NOT a question which has been answered in the past!
It was working yesterday.That it happened on the first of the month is suspicious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the Yahoo site status. We're not support for any third-party off site location or vendor. Contact that site directly to inquire about their status. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as well on my side, it was all good yesterday. Anyone have a working API code?

Comment: Many people are having this problem, but congratulations - your site remains pure.

Comment: They change public type to private for some tables, but (server-side, without yahoo login, only with app key and app secret) auth api doesn't exist

Comment: It seems like they know about the issue, and intended to fix it. 
https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Known-issues-and-updates/Finance-download-error-999/m-p/387511#M13

Comment: New message from Yahoo Admin "... the service is being discontinued..."
https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Known-issues-and-updates/Finance-download-errors/td-p/387511

Comment: Someone already flagged/voted to close this as a "not coding related" vote. Maybe not "coding" but "coders". Code is nothing, people (coders) are something. Many probably don't know how to handle this. Some probably don't know what PHP errors or how to interpret them.

Comment: Addendum to my above comment. I know how to deal with code-related issues. That is the only control we/I have, we just can't control who runs the show. TBH, Stack wasn't my first stop in researching this issue, I was more after going for the "real" reason as to why Yahoo suddenly just "pulled the plug" as it were. Actually, [this is the first site](https://www.stockmarketeye.com/blog/quote-issues-due-to-changes-at-yahoo-finance/) I found/visited.

Comment: This is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358883/1415724).

Answer (score 18):

As noted in the other answers and elsewhere (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076404/currency-helper-of-yahoo-sorry-unable-to-process-request-at-this-time-erro/47096766#47096766), Yahoo has indeed ceased operation of the Yahoo Finance API.  However, as a workaround, you can access a trove of financial information, in JSON format, for a given ticker symbol, by doing a HTTPS GET request to: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SYMBOL (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT).  If you do a GET request to the above URL, you'll see that the financial data is contained within the response in JSON format.  The following python3 script shows how you can parse individual values that you may be interested in:

```py
import requests
import json

symbol = 'MSFT'
url ='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol
resp = requests.get(url)

# parse the section from the html document containing the raw json data that we need
# you can write jsonstr to a file, then open the file in a web browser to browse the structure of the json data
r = str(resp.content, 'utf-8')
i1 = 0
i1 = r.find('root.App.main', i1)
i1 = r.find('{', i1)
i2 = r.find("\n", i1)
i2 = r.rfind(';', i1, i2)
jsonstr = r[i1:i2]      

# load the raw json data into a python data object
data = json.loads(jsonstr)

# pull the values that we are interested in 
name = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['price']['shortName']
price = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['price']['regularMarketPrice']['raw']
change = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['price']['regularMarketChange']['raw']
shares_outstanding = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['defaultKeyStatistics']['sharesOutstanding']['raw']
market_cap = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['summaryDetail']['marketCap']['raw']
trailing_pe = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['summaryDetail']['trailingPE']['raw']
earnings_per_share = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['defaultKeyStatistics']['trailingEps']['raw']
forward_annual_dividend_rate = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['summaryDetail']['dividendRate']['raw']
forward_annual_dividend_yield = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['summaryDetail']['dividendYield']['raw']

# print the values
print('Symbol:', symbol)
print('Name:', name)
print('Price:', price)
print('Change:', change)
print('Shares Outstanding:', shares_outstanding)
print('Market Cap:', market_cap)
print('Trailing PE:', trailing_pe)
print('Earnings Per Share:', earnings_per_share)
print('Forward Annual Dividend Rate:', forward_annual_dividend_rate)
print('Forward_annual_dividend_yield:', forward_annual_dividend_yield)
```

Comment: Is there any javascript equivalence of this Python implementation? Thanks.

Comment: As of now, when I put `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT` into a browser's address bar what comes back is not JSON, but a pretty formatted HTML page.

Comment: @mbmast - It may be that the server is responding differently to the request from the browser, based on the headers that the browser is sending.  I tested again just now using the python script above, and it produced the expected results.  I've also updated the script for python3.

Comment: @mti2935 Right.  I had forgotten about User Agent and things like that.

Comment: @mbmast -  Actually, if you point your browser to the URL (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT), then view the source of the page, you'll see that the JSON is in there.

Answer (score 17):

Yahoo [confirmed](https://yahoo.sdx.socialdynamx.com/portal/conversation/19248672) that they terminated the service:

> It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com .

Comment: I don't get Yahoo's response.

Comment: It's more like Yahoo *Doesn't* Care.

Comment: @AlenSiljak Oh they care alright; for money and that's probably what this is really about, that they'll end up offering it again but people/businesses/coders will have to pay for it.

Comment: Addendum to my above comment: Yahoo was bought out by Verizon. I'm sure that that has something to do with this and it's coming from up above; a place that anyone seldomly sees or gets wind about.

Comment: @MarkAmery Pretty much.

Comment: there goes the explanation of why yahoo went down the drain in the last 20 years

Comment: As far as I recall this API was unofficial and so what I don't understand is all these people being pissed off at Yahoo. They need to make money and they get that from eyeballs on advertising, anyone using a direct URL is circumventing that and like they stated it is against their terms.

Answer (score 8):

There is still a way to get this data by querying some APIs used by the finance.yahoo.com page. Not sure if Yahoo will be supporting it long term as the previous API was (hopefully they will).

I adapted the method used by https://github.com/pstadler/ticker.sh into the following python hack that takes a list of symbols from the command line and outputs some of the variables as a csv:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import requests

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("missing parameters: <symbol> ...")
    exit()

apiEndpoint = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote"
fields = [
    'symbol',
    'regularMarketVolume',
    'regularMarketPrice',
    'regularMarketDayHigh',
    'regularMarketDayLow',
    'regularMarketTime',
    'regularMarketChangePercent']
fields = ','.join(fields)
symbols = sys.argv[1:]
symbols = ','.join(symbols)
payload = {
    'lang': 'en-US',
    'region': 'US',
    'corsDomain': 'finance.yahoo.com',
    'fields': fields,
    'symbols': symbols}
r = requests.get(apiEndpoint, params=payload)
for i in r.json()['quoteResponse']['result']:
    if 'regularMarketPrice' in i:
        a = []
        a.append(i['symbol'])
        a.append(i['regularMarketPrice'])
        a.append(time.strftime(
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(i['regularMarketTime'])))
        a.append(i['regularMarketChangePercent'])
        a.append(i['regularMarketVolume'])
        a.append("{0:.2f} - {1:.2f}".format(
            i['regularMarketDayLow'], i['regularMarketDayHigh']))
        print(",".join([str(e) for e in a]))
```

Sample Run:

```
$ ./getquotePy.py AAPL GOOGL
AAPL,174.5342,2017-11-07 17:21:28,0.1630961,19905458,173.60 - 173.60
GOOGL,1048.6753,2017-11-07 17:21:22,0.5749836,840447,1043.00 - 1043.00
```

Answer (score 7):

`var API = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=AAPL";
$.getJSON(API, function (json) {...});`call throws this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.microplan.at/sar' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This seems to work fine from a browser, and return json.

Comment: they might discontinue this service as well