# Url http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv.. is not working

Tags: csv

I am using the url http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv.. in my application to receive the currency conversion rate.Up to yesterday, it was retrieving data with no error.But today it throws exception "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." in my code.When i paste the url in browser it says "It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com."

What is the actual cause?What are the alternate ways to retrieve the currency conversion from yahoo?Please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has Yahoo suddenly today terminated its finance download API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064776/has-yahoo-suddenly-today-terminated-its-finance-download-api)

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's all fine with your code - Yahoo just discarded this functionality without any warning to community -.-

https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/http-download-finance-yahoo-com-d-quotes-csv-s-GOOG-amp-f/m-p/387662/highlight/true#M6207

IMO it's worthy to just write new parser using Google services. That's very nasty from Yahoo side to just close some widely used feature so rapidly.
I decided to use this currency calculator: https://finance.google.com/finance/converter

Comment: Ok.But i have tried today using https://finance.google.com/finance/converter, but it also doesn't working.There are lot of example in C#. i downloaded but not a single example was working.Only from UI(https://finance.google.com/finance/converter) it working, but from code it doesn't work.

Comment: I used this Google converter, because it's ought to be easy to write your own parser. I wrote one myself and it works perfectly fine. Because I don't know technology which you're using, I'll explain logic of parser:
When you want to extract EUR/PLN currency rate, you need to insert "from=EUR" and "to=PLN" to link as below:
https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=EUR&to=PLN
Then you can extract current rate value from div with id = "currency_converter_result" - please use DOM inspector (CTRL + Shift + C) to get exact HTML structure to parse.