# Did Yahoo Finance just discontinue their CSV download?

Tags: yahoo-finance

This used to work yesterday:
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT

Now I get this message:
It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com.

But this makes no sense. Finance.Yahoo.com isn't a download that is usable in excel or a program. Does Yahoo still have a way to do this via some other URL or did they just cut us all off? Does anyone know a good alternative?

Comment: It was free and now it's probably amount (asking for) money. Oh yeah, *duh...*  *"Yahoo **Finance**",* what was I thinking?

Comment: This is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358883/1415724).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064776/has-yahoo-suddenly-today-terminated-its-finance-download-api/47148296#47148296 for a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they just discontinued it without a warning ... It's such a shame it's so difficult to find a free source of stock quotes. This information should be in the public domain.

---

[EDIT] I found this alternative, which is free and seems reliable: [www.alphavantage.co](https://www.alphavantage.co).

It works for stock quotes (US-only though) and currency rates.
Only thing we can't do is ask for several stocks at the same time, you need to send several requests (hello DispatchGroup).

Comment: Alternative workaround using Google Sheets - working fine for me.
https://office-watch.com/2016/excel-stock-prices-from-google-finance/

Comment: Anywhere we can get dividend history?