# Need in understanding Exception at runtime in C++/CLI project execution

Tags: c#, c++, interop, managed

I am using [Code](http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/) from here, it is a simple code that allows Managed C# class to be used inside a C++ project with CLI bridge. And I am trying to get this working for my testing. But I get this exception :

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDAA264008 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131509, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD798F0000). occurred
>
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDAA264008 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131509, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD798F0000).
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDAA264008 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131509, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD798F0000).
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDAA264008 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131509, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD798F0000).
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDAA264008 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131509, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD798F0000).
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDAA264008 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131509, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD798F0000).
> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDAA264008 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131509, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD798F0000).

I tried dependency walker, for the test.exe and I couldn't find any tangible problems except some API-MS-WIN-CORE* dlls missing. It did say one module has an unresolved import due to missing export function , but where do I find this ? It also says 1 circular dependency detected and one not found.

See the attached picture.
[image: Dependency Walker]

Please advice.

Comment: You have bugs in the code.  Using the debugger and single stepping the problem area is the correct tool/approach.

Comment: 0xE0434352 is the exception code for a managed exception, 80131509 says that it is a InvalidOperationException.  Probably something simple, but it does get pretty hard to diagnose such exceptions from native code.  This does require that you use logging or make the invoked code capable of generating a reasonable error code.  Get ahead first by debugging this mishap.  Project > Properties > Debugging > Debugger Type = mixed.  And force the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown with Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick the CLR checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I should have enabled the CLR exceptions to see that it was Unable to resolve host exception from the .NET side. This was happening since this service has been discontinued by Yahoo [Has Yahoo suddenly today terminated its finance download API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064776/has-yahoo-suddenly-today-terminated-its-finance-download-api)
.

Whew, I could not have figured this out with out all the helpful pointers. Thanks guys, I am marking this resolved.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your program is passing null into parameters 2,3,4 on a function at memory location 0xE0434352. Hence the:

```
0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80131509, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFD798F0000).
```

My guess is that the function 0xE0434352 is not expecting null parameters at these locations. I would double check all your culls into the various functions that set up this dll to make sure that nothing is null or not defined.

Comment: 0xE0434352 is not a function, it's the exception's numeric code. As such, parameters are not function parameters, but arbitrary "data" (their meaning is dependent on the exception's "type").