# ClassNotFound Exception in YahooFinanace API

Tags: java, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I have downloaded and initialized the `pom.xml` file as said in the API: https://financequotes-api.com/

While trying to run this code:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Stock stock = YahooFinance.get("BABA");      
        BigDecimal price = stock.getQuote().getPrice();
        BigDecimal change = stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent();
        BigDecimal peg = stock.getStats().getPeg();
        BigDecimal dividend = stock.getDividend().getAnnualYieldPercent();

        stock.print();  
     }
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
yahoofinance/YahooFinance
   at stox.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: yahoofinance.YahooFinance
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   ... 1 more
```

The `yahoofinance.YahooFinance` is definitely there, so I don't understand why it is failing. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: I thought yahoo finance was deprecated. Is it not? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048671/alternatives-to-the-yahoo-finance-api

Comment: Well, it looks like it. Thanks!