# Yahoo Finance down loader stopped working

Tags: java, connection, yahoo

I have a JAVA program that i have been using for the last year to downlaod data from yahoo finance. A few days ago it stopped working and yahoo started to refuse the connection.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class C_GetStocksFromYahoo {
    public Scanner input;

    public void GetStocks(String symbol, GregorianCalendar start, GregorianCalendar end) {  
        String url = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
            + symbol
            + "&a=" + start.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            + "&b=" + start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            + "&c=" + start.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            + "&d=" + end.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            + "&e=" +end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            + "&f=" + end.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            + "&g=d&ignore=.csv"; //g=d means daily stock quotes

        try {
            URL yhoofin=new URL(url);//Create New URL data
            URLConnection data=yhoofin.openConnection();//Open a connection
            input = new Scanner(data.getInputStream());//get data from input stream 
            //System.out.println("This is the scanner " + input);
            //System.out.println("This is the first line " + this.nextline());
            //System.out.println("This is the first line " + this.nextline());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("This is the symbol i failed on " + symbol);
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    //scanner value
    public Scanner getScan() {
        return input;
    }

    //determine if file has next entry
    public boolean hasnext() {
        return input.hasNext();
    }

    //contains next line
    public String nextline() {
        return input.nextLine();
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work inside a browser ?

Comment: Sorry not a very experienced programmer. I have been running this as a JAVA application. How do you run it inside a browser?

Comment: Just copy-paste the content of your `url` `String` to the adress bar of your browser, and see if you get the result page (I just tried to paste "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv", it gave error 404 / host unreachable) .

Comment: I tried and it does not work. it appears they changed the address to something very difficult to read. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Yahoo discontinued their API for historical data, therefor your URL `http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?` won't get you any data back anymore.

On https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503/page/3 Nixon (Official 'Hoo Staff) said:

> Hi All - This feature was discontinued by the Finance team and they will not be reintroducing that functionality.

Taken from: [Yahoo Finance URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working)