# Yahoo YQL yahoo.finance.historicaldata returning empty results

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I have developed and tested with the this API last week. Today I am noticing I am not receiving any results even from the sample query.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+Close+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+%3D+%22EUR%3DX%22+and+startDate+%3D+%222015-09-11%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222017-03-10%22

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22YHOO%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222009-09-11%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222010-03-10%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Yahoo! decided to discontinue their historical data API :-(

Taken from the yahoo finance forum: https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503/page/3

Nixon (Official 'Hoo staff) posted:

> Hi All - This feature was discontinued by the Finance team and they will not be reintroducing that functionality.

Comment: Dammit! I just finished the integration!

Comment: I know right? User @Ed0906 has some ideas on how to grab the data regardless: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working/44050039#44050039