# Understanding yahoo_quote_download

Tags: python, csv, yahoo-finance

Since Yahoo Finance terminated its service to download EoD prices data, I have come across the following Python script [yahoo_quote_download](https://github.com/c0redumb/yahoo_quote_download) to continue downloading the data I require.   Unfortunately, I am completely new to Python, and I am struggling with using this promising tool.

I am running Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS X.  Having followed the installation instructions of the script, I have not observed any error messages.  The readme.md file states the following:

> The CSV file downloaded through the new API has a few data and format differences from the CSV file from the original iChart source.

Most likely due to the fact that I am completely new to Python, I fail to find the syntax for the Python code to download data into a CSV-file as mentioned in the readme file.

Playing around with amongst others the test_yqd.py gives only screen output, for instance:

```
bash-3.2$ python test_yqd.py
('===', 'FP.PA', '===')
[u'Date,Dividends', u'2015-06-08,0.61', u'2016-06-06,0.61', u'2014-12-15,0.61', u'2014-03-24,0.59', u'2015-03-23,0.61', u'2016-03-21,0.61', u'2017-03-20,0.61', u'2014-09-23,0.61', u'2015-12-21,0.61', u'2015-09-28,0.61', u'2016-09-27,0.61', u'2016-12-21,0.61', u'2014-06-02,0.61', u'']
bash-3.2$
```

This is promising, because I have tested a few data sets, and I seem to get access to all of the data I require, unfortunately my attempts have failed to download a CSV file with the data.

Practically, I seek to find the syntax that invokes the Python script and downloads the data into a CSV.  Subsequently, I can pick up the CSV file and update my database and perform analysis.  What is the Python command I need to invoke with which arguments to download a CSV file?

Any help that leads to understanding and using the yahoo_quote_download scripts will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV stands for "Comma Separated Values", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values.

So this data below you got from calling the code is the CSV.

```
[u'Date,Dividends', u'2015-06-08,0.61', u'2016-06-06,0.61', u'2014-12-15,0.61', u'2014-03-24,0.59', u'2015-03-23,0.61', u'2016-03-21,0.61', u'2017-03-20,0.61', u'2014-09-23,0.61', u'2015-12-21,0.61', u'2015-09-28,0.61', u'2016-09-27,0.61', u'2016-12-21,0.61', u'2014-06-02,0.61', u'']
```

Each of these is a line, and within each line there are two fields separated by a comma. CSV file is nothing more than the CSV data written into a file. If you need a CSV file, you just need to write this data into a file, one line at a time (i.e., you need to add a new line after each item).

It does not look like your issue is with Python coding. Hope it helps.

Comment: Cheers c0redumb, I simply substituted `print(yqd.load_yahoo_quote(ticker, '20170515', '20170530'))` with: `with open('out.csv', 'wb') as myfile: wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter='\n') wr.writerow(yqd.load_yahoo_quote(ticker, '20170515', '20170530'))` and the whole things seems to run smoothly.