# Yahoo Finance intraday data with new API (May 2017)

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

After the last changes in the Yahoo Finance API, I was able to use the new API in order to download historical data at day intervals following the responses of this question:
[Yahoo Finance URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working)

With new API, I'm refering to URLs of this type:

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1492524105&period2=1495116105&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=tO1hNZoUQeQ
cookie: B=xxxxxxxx&b=3&s=qf;
```

However, I'm interested in intraday data. I've tried to modify the query parameters without success. So, is it possible to use the new API to get also intraday data? Any clue or documentation/tutorial is very welcome.

Many thanks!

Comment: check this perl script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379067/new-yahoo-finance-historical-data

Comment: Many thanks for your help negi, however the perl script is intended to download day data (notice that the parameter interval is equal to 1 day). I'm interested in intraday data, using for example 1 minute intervals.

Comment: Have you found a solution by any chance?

Comment: Actually no, so now I'm using Google API. Here is an example of Apple stock prices (1 minute interval) for the last two days: https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=AAPL&x=NASDAQ&i=60&p=2d&f=d,c,h,l,o,v You can find more (non official) information about meaning of the parameters in this blog: http://www.networkerror.org/component/content/article/1-technical-wootness/44-googles-undocumented-finance-api.html