# Using PHP to download Stock Data History from Yahoo Finance

Tags: php, fopen, yahoo

Yahoo have changed the url format for downloading stock data, which doesn't work using fopen anymore

For example:

```
fopen('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AMZN?period1=1483920000&period2=1484006400&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=SqQAebjmGVM','rb');
```

url downloads an excel file in a browser, but returns ***false*** from PHP script?

Comment: I get a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` with JSON response of `{
    "finance": {
        "error": {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "description": "Invalid cookie"
        }
    }
}` when attempting to access that URL via cURL.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Here is your answer to your question. Check this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44050039/2267690

Comment: Good catch, @RanjeetSingh.