# Yahoo finance historical data by csv

Tags: api, csv, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I am used to getting data from Yahoo Finance by url in csv with a simple url request:

```
$data_url="http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=".$code."&d=".$m."&e=".$d."&f=".$y."&g=d&a=".$a."&b=".$b."&c=".$c."&ignore=.csv";
```

Then suddenly it stopped working, so I tried with many others but nothing.

```
$data_url="https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=".$code."&d=".$m."&e=".$d."&f=".$y."&g=d&a=".$a."&b=".$b."&c=".$c."&ignore=.csv";
$data_url="https://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=".$code."&d=".$m."&e=".$d."&f=".$y."&g=d&a=".$a."&b=".$b."&c=".$c."&ignore=.csv";
$data_url="https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=".$code."&d=".$m."&e=".$d."&f=".$y."&g=d&a=".$a."&b=".$b."&c=".$c."&ignore=.csv";
$data_url="https://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=".$code."&d=".$m."&e=".$d."&f=".$y."&g=d&a=".$a."&b=".$b."&c=".$c."&ignore=.csv";
```

I checked [Yahoo Finance URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working/44036220)

But for php it seems there is no solution. Can someone help me in building the php code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yahoo Finance URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

[The Yahoo Finance API was discontinued](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503) and will not be reintroduced.

Answer (score 0):

We use the Yahoo Finance API to grab daily rates and historical rates.   The daily rates is still working for us using a URL to query.   The historical rates are returning results but say the day is invalid (such as a weekend).   Where did you see the Finance API is discontinued as I still get daily rates.