# Download a csv from url and make it a dataframe python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python so need a little help here. I have a dataframe with a url column with a link that allows me to download a CSV for each link. My aim is to create a loop/ whatever works so that I can run one command that will allow me to download,read the csv and create a dataframe for each of the rows. Any help would be appreciated. I have attached part of the dataframe below. If the link doesn't work (it probably won't you can just replace it with a link from 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?p=GOOG' (any other company too) and navigate to download csv and use that link.

Dataframe:

```
Symbol         Link
YI             https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/YI?period1=1383609600&period2=1541376000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=PMHbxK/sU6E
PIH            https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/PIH?period1=1383609600&period2=1541376000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=PMHbxK/sU6E
TURN           https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TURN?period1=1383609600&period2=1541376000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=PMHbxK/sU6E
FLWS           https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/FLWS?period1=1383609600&period2=1541376000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=PMHbxK/sU6E
```

Thanks again.

Comment: The website uses cookies to deliver content. First try downloading a single file programmatically (through something like [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) or `selenium`, and try to understand how the website uses the cookies, and then you can try to loop through all the urls.

Answer (score 21):

There are multiple ways to get CSV data from URLs. From your example, namely Yahoo Finance, you can copy the `Historical`  data link and call it in Pandas

```py
...
HISTORICAL_URL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG?period1=1582781719&period2=1614404119&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"

df = pd.read_csv(HISTORICAL_URL)
```

A general pattern could involve tools like `requests` or `httpx` to make a GET|POST request and then get the contents to `io`.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG'
params ={'period1':1538761929,
         'period2':1541443929,
         'interval':'1d',
         'events':'history',
         'crumb':'v4z6ZpmoP98',
        }

r = requests.post(url,data=params)
if r.ok:
    data = r.content.decode('utf8')
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
```

To get the params, I just followed the liked and copied everything after ‘?’. Check that they match ;)

Results:
[image]

Update:

---

If you can see the raw csv contents directly in url, just pass the url in `pd.read_csv`
Example data directly from url:

```
data_url ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/iris.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(data_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I routinely use this procedure

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url="<URL TO DOWNLOAD.CSV>"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(s)
```

Comment: This only gets the result for one value rather than the entire dataframe like he wants

Answer (score 0):

First break down the task to smaller parts, what you need to do is:

1. Iterate over the DataFrame with the links.

   ```
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
       url= row["Link"]
   ```
2. Download JSON file from Yahoo Finance using Python's `requests` library. This is probably the difficult part, you will need to get cookies before actually downloading the CSV file, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working/44168805),[here](https://github.com/sjev/trading-with-python/blob/3.1.1/lib/yahooFinance.py) and [here](https://github.com/c0redumb/yahoo_quote_download). Once you create the proper URL with the cookie, you can download it with:

   ```
   re = requests.get(URL)
   print(re.status_code) #status code 200 for successful download
   ```
3. Optionally, you can save the response to your local disk.
4. Load it with pandas.

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv(file_name) #in case of saving file to disk
   df = pd.read_csv(re.content) #directly from the response
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the following to the dataframe it will place each of the documents in an np.array. Not in a dataframe( I'm unsure of how to get there). But this will give you access to all the files and its only a matter of putting them in a df.

```
links = test['Link'].unique()

import requests
a=[]
for x in links:
     url=x
     s=requests.get(url).content
     a.append(s)
```

`a[4] or np.array(a[4]).tolist()` outputs the entire file just in the incorrect format.

> Use 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/GOOG/chart/5y?format=csv' rather than Yahoo it is much more accessible.