# Tesla api stock price

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, urllib

I am very new to Python and looking for a way to get the current stock price of TESLA.
I have this program but it prints out way too much. I am running python 3 connecting to the school
computer via Linux. I can not install Pandas, pip requests or conda because I am not authorized.
I even tried sudo. I was hoping to find an api something like this: http://api.bart.gov/api/route.aspx?
but for tesla. I appreciate any help I can get. At this point ucllib seems to work getting the url.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
params = { "key": "MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V", "cmd": "routes" }
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/history?period1=1436486400&period2=1594339200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d" + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as result:
  print(result.read())
```

Comment: If you only need the price then you can just use Excel. Type TESLA in a cell and click convert to Stock.

Answer (score 1):

Use [https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/tsla?modules=price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working#47505102)

```
import urllib.request, json
resp = urllib.request.urlopen('https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/tsla?modules=price')
data = json.loads(resp.read())
price = data['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['price']['regularMarketPrice']['raw']
print(price)
```

Comment: I get this error. $ python3 stock6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stock6.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = json.loads(resp.read()$ python3 stock6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stock6.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = json.loads(resp.read()

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps you tried too many times and got throttled? The error indicates that what you got back wasn't proper JSON. Maybe inspect the response that you got; it might contain an error message with more information.

Comment: Wow! This works perfect. Thanks a bunch. I have been working on this since Monday.