# Yahoo finance cookie and crumb not working

Tags: java, cookies, finance, yahoo

I am trying to scrape the cookie and crumb from Yahoo finance in Java to get daily stock price histories.

I modified code from the post [Yahoo Finance URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working), but it does not seem to be working.  In particular, when searching for the crumb, the word "CrumbStore" does not seem to appear in the search text anywhere:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetYahooQuotes {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        String cookie = null;

    try {
            // Open the URL connection
        URL url = new URL("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : con.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() == null || !entry.getKey().equals("Set-Cookie"))
                    continue;
                for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
                    // store your cookie
                    cookie = s;
                    System.out.println( "Cookie = " + cookie);
                }
            }

        String crumb = null;
        InputStream inStream = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader irdr = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
        BufferedReader rsv = new BufferedReader(irdr);

        Pattern crumbPattern = Pattern.compile(".*\"CrumbStore\":\\{\"crumb\":\"([^\"]+)\"\\}.*");

        String line = null;
        while (crumb == null && (line = rsv.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher matcher = crumbPattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                crumb = matcher.group(1);
                System.out.println( "Crumb = " + crumb);
            }
        }
        rsv.close();
    }
        catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // The URL connection timed out.  Try again.
        }
    }
}
```

Also, when storing the cookie, it seems like there are three different cookies.  Which one should I use?
My output is:

```
Cookie = A1S=d=AQABBLeLr2MCEKfVotZCLRRvj9tdxyruiIkFEgEBAQHdsGO5YwAAAAAA_eMAAA&S=AQAAAtgfY5LB0heCm1MP9BNfRAA&j=WORLD; Domain=.yahoo.com; Path=/; SameSite=Lax; Secure
Cookie = A3=d=AQABBLeLr2MCEKfVotZCLRRvj9tdxyruiIkFEgEBAQHdsGO5YwAAAAAA_eMAAA&S=AQAAAtgfY5LB0heCm1MP9BNfRAA; Expires=Sun, 31 Dec 2023 07:09:12 GMT; Max-Age=31557600; Domain=.yahoo.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly
Cookie = A1=d=AQABBLeLr2MCEKfVotZCLRRvj9tdxyruiIkFEgEBAQHdsGO5YwAAAAAA_eMAAA&S=AQAAAtgfY5LB0heCm1MP9BNfRAA; Expires=Sun, 31 Dec 2023 07:09:12 GMT; Max-Age=31557600; Domain=.yahoo.com; Path=/; SameSite=Lax; Secure; HttpOnly
```

I understand that when I get the crumb, I will have to call something like:

```
String quoteUrl = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/IBM?period1=1493425217&period2=1496017217&interval=1d&events=history&crumb="
                           + crumb
```

but I am not there yet.  I still need help on how to get the crumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secure cookie is the cookie I would use out of the three, that way you have a better bet on avoiding 401 unauthorized errors. I also wouldn't doubt if the "CrumbStore" property has been renamed or even removed, as the post you referenced dates back to 2017. I would try some cURL requests or use Postman to try to find what the exact parameter names are.

I found a snippet that also utilizes `java.net.UrlConnection` and instead of trying to find some type of regular expression pattern, it just searches through the headers of the request. It retrieves the cookie in the process as well.

```
String headerName = null;
String crumb = null;
for (int i = 1; (headerName = con.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
    if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
        String cookie = con.getHeaderField(i);
        cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
        crumb = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.indexOf("&"));
    }
}
```

And perhaps you can integrate it into your existing code like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : con.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey() == null || !entry.getKey().equals("Set-Cookie"))
        continue;
        for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
            // store your cookie
            cookie = s;
            System.out.println( "Cookie = " + cookie);
            String crumb = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.indexOf("&"));
            System.out.println( "Crumb = " + crumb);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MaxVoisard.  Your code for finding the crumb worked brilliantly.  Note, all three cookies gave the same crumb.  I am just using the first cookie and everything is working well.

Comment: @sawong Good to hear. Please upvote and/or mark as the accepted answer!